# How to make a health bar with individual boxes?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a health bar similar to Overwatch with individual little bars. So each bar would be 20% of their health. So there would be 5 bars. The first bar would be from 1 - 20% health, the next 21 - 40%, etc. I can't figure it out though. This is what I have so far:

```
public static double health = 100;
public static double maxHealth = 100;
//Each bar should only be 20 percent of their health (This one from 80 - 100)
public static double usePercent = maxHealth * 80 / 100;
public static double healthPercent = health / maxHealth * 100;
//Percent of health the bar should be
public static double percentUse = healthPercent - usePercent;

public static void onHealthChange(int newHealth)
{
    double newHealthPercent = newHealth / maxHealth * 100;
    //Percent of health bar should be after updated health
    double newPercentUse = Math.abs(newHealthPercent - usePercent);

    //Making sure that their health is high enough for this bar
    //Ex: if their health is 80+ it would be on the fifth bar
    if(newHealthPercent >= usePercent)
    {
        //The percentage of the bar that should be used
        double percentBar = newPercentUse / percentUse * 100;

        //The size of each bar is 25
        double size = percentBar * 25 / 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having with your code?

Comment: *I can't figure it out though.* You can't figure what out?

Comment: The size doesn't come out right.

Comment: Did you debug your code to see why? What do you get and what would you expect? What does that magic number 200 in the last code line mean? Also, what does `size` mean? Is it the size of _one_ bar? What about the others then? How do you calculate which bar should be the partially visible one?

Comment: I haven't real trouble figuring out what `usePercent` is supposed to do. `usePercent` is always 80% (for these values), so if their `healthPercent` is 50%, their `percentUse` is -30%?

Comment: Whoops that was supposed to be 100 to get the percentage. And yes size is the size of one bar. And I haven't done that yet I just wanted to figure out the math behind it first.

Comment: usePercent is supposed to be at what percent of health the bar gets used. So the last bar would be from 80 - 100%. And with these values I got percentUse to be 20% for the 20% of health that this bar would represent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of it as follows. Given an "increment", the amount of health in each bar, of 20:

- For health bar 1, find the percentage for `health / 20`
- For health bar 2, find the percentage for `(health - 20) / 20`
- For health bar 3, find the percentage for `(health - 40) / 20`
- For health bar 4, find the percentage for `(health - 60) / 20`
- For health bar 5, find the percentage for `(health - 80) / 20`

We can generalise that to:

- For health bar `n`, find the percentage for `(health - ((n-1) * increment)) / increment`

This is fine, but if the current health is 100, the first health bar will get a percentage `100 / 20 = 500%`. We can solve this by "clamping" the values. The lowest we can go is 0% (you can't have a negatively filled health bar) and the highest we can go is 100% (you can't have an over-filled heath bar). We can use Java's [`Math.min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-double-double-) and [`Math.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-double-double-) for this.

It's also often more convenient to use the range zero to one, rather than zero to 100, when representing fractions. I've done this in my example.

This is how I'd do it:

```
private static final int NUM_HEALTH_BARS = 5;

private double health = 35;
private final double maxHealth = 80;

private final HealthBar[] healthBars = /* whatever */;

public void onHealthChange(final int newHealth)
{
    this.health = newHealth;
    updateHealthBars();
}

private void updateHealthBars()
{
    final double increment = maxHealth / NUM_HEALTH_BARS;

    for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_HEALTH_BARS; ++i)
    {
        double howFull = (health - ((i - 1) * increment)) / increment;
        howFull = Math.min(howFull, 1.0);
        howFull = Math.max(howFull, 0.0);

        // howFull is 0 to 1, so times by 100 if you need it as a percentage:

        healthBars[i].setFull(howFull * 100);
    }
}
```